# Azure App Service Environment Access Levels

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-api-apps

I am setting up API Apps within ASE, and I was having some difficulties understanding the usage of access levels.

I noticed that if the API App access level is set to “Internal” it’s not accessible publicly, however, I do not get an internal endpoint, just a public one – so I am unable to access this application internally (for example – browsing to it from a VM in the same network).
How can I access the API App from say a virtual machine hosted on Azure? How can I get an internal endpoint for an API App?

My goal is to be able to access the API App from my VNet, and to have public access blocked.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out API Apps only have a single end-point which is a public VIP.
Need to create a network security group on the subnet and add explicit rules for public VIP's of back-end machines that require access to the API. This will block internet traffic to the app when it is on public anonymous.